# Drag an errorbar around in a plot in qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qpainter

I am using QPainter in Qt 5.9 using C++ to make a plot and update it based on mouse events.

I would like to know how to plot an error bar that is something like this:

```
-
|
-
```

Of course the gaps shouldn't be there between the vertical and horizontal lines.

I need to be able to drag the error bar around on the plot and obtain the co-ordiantes of the center position of the error bar when the mouse button is released. So far I have made a plot with axes and labels. Not sure how to get the error bar using QPainter or any other Qt lib class.

Please provide some insight on how make/plot the error bars. Is there a simple way to do that in QPainter ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using QPainter you should implement drag-n-drop yourself. It's not that difficult if you don't have too many objects on your plot.

Here's the basic idea:

First of all render all objects. Than you need to reimplement `mousePressEvent` and `mouseMoveEvent` in your plot widget. In `mousePressEvent` you should check if you've clicked on the draggable object and define this object as currently being dragged. In `mouseMoveEvent` just move this object (if there is one) by changing its coordinates and rerender plot.

You will probably want to optimize plotting to avoid full plot rerender at each mouse move tick. This can be achieved by plotting rarely changing objects to `QPixmap`/`QImage`, than rendering this `QPixmap`/`QImage` on widget and than plotting error bars and all other kinds of objects that could change at each mouse move tick over this pixmap. At each repaint you will need to define if you need to replot just error bars (or some other dynamic objects) or all widget. I personally implement this by defining `bool needFullRepaint` which is set to `false` by widget after each render tick and is set to `true` after some data inside widget changed.

This is kinda low-level approach, it will require high level of skill and some time to be spend but you will be awarded with maximum control of the rendering and interactions with the widget, which is not always possible with the `QGraphicsScene` or `QCharts`

Comment: Thanks. So I do have that structure laid out now and have the basic events working. I am just not sure how to make the error bars. I have been trying to work on it but I havent been able to get it right.

Comment: What exactly aren't you able to do? Use QPainter::drawLine as a simpliest way to render the figure in your question

Comment: To make the error bar. The lines are all screwed up.

Answer (score 0):

1. It's going to be a fairly involved project for someone who hasn't used Qt before.
2. You will want to use [QGraphicsScene](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscene.html) in all likelihood, rather than a QPainter example. QGraphicsScenes are way easier than QPainter for interactive examples.
3. Use QCharts as a starting point, they have examples for how to plot data and then move items as a result. Check out the [callout](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcharts-callout-example.html) example, in particular, which has you paint a callout labeling the position of the cursor on the graph.
4. Look at the ["Drag and Drop Robot"](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-graphicsview-dragdroprobot-example.html) example from Qt.

All of these are an excellent starting point for how to implement draggable features to create an interactive plot. Qt makes it easy for a generalized sense: however, for many plotting features (at least until QtCharts), Qt was much more difficult than specialized plotting libraries.

Comment: thanks for the help. I already have the plots running using QPaint. It would be too much extra effort to move over to QChart. I think there is a way but I might not be able to drag it around. Let me know if you can come up with a way using QPainter to drag a point around using a mouse click

Comment: You can, but it would mean storing state and reimplementing the `paintEvent()` and then drawing items conditionally based on stored data. It's very doable, just a lot more work. I can give you examples of widgets that do this.